# I want to add repositories to my linux distribution of another version

Tags: ubuntu, repository, distributions

I am using the distribution of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop, this version no longer works its repositories, I want to add the repositories of the version of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS that its repositories still work, how could I achieve this? please help

Comment: Over on the Ubuntu site, [How to upgrade a server from 12.04 to 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/779189/473234)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade.

This will not work for the vast majority of applications and by doing so and actually installing packages you will break your DPKG database and render apt/dpkg broken.

Comment: So how do you manage to update the dependencies and applications without changing the distro?

Comment: For the record: You can add `xenial` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. `apt-get` will prefer the new packages over the old `precise` versions. Next time you want to install something, a (partial) upgrade will be performed. It will be messy. It can work, though (Debian actually does upgrades exactly this way). May the deity of your choice be with you.

Comment: Of course there has to be a way to do it.

Comment: @CargoLT no there is no other way than what Artem says. What you want is really an update. Using newer software requires using newer libraries, which the newer Ubuntu repo brings. Using the newer Ubuntu repo literally is how you upgrade an Ubuntu.